do we have an estimate $\|\partial_v u\|_{H^{-1/2}} \leq \|\nabla u\|_{L^{2}(\partial\Omega)}$?
Let $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ such that $u$ is a solution for the problem $Lu = F$ in $\Omega$ and $u = g$ on $\partial\Omega$, where $g \in H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$ and $F \in L^2(\Omega)$. We assume that $\Omega$ is a Lipschitz domain.
Clearly we have $|\partial_v u|=|v\cdot\nabla u| \leq \|\nabla u\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}$ for a smooth function, where $v$ is outer normal unit vector.
Do we have an estimate $\|\partial_v u\|_{H^{-1/2}(\partial\Omega)} \leq \|\nabla u\|_{L^{2}(\partial\Omega)}$, where the conormal derivative $\partial_v u$ is defined in a weak sense?
One way of proving this is via density argument i think, but im not sure how the density results apply at the boundary of a set.

How do you define $|\nabla u|_{H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)}$ if $u$ is only in $H^1(\Omega)$?

yes, it should be $L^2$norm instead

you also have $| \partial_v u|{L^2(\partial \Omega)} \le | \nabla u |{L^2(\partial \Omega)} $ trivially.

$\nabla u$ is still not defined on $\partial\Omega$.

it is since $g\in H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$, so actually also $|\nabla u|_{H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)}$ is well-defined

Ah, I see. But then it should be the $H^{-1/2}(\partial\Omega)$ norm.

but i need $H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$ norm

no, i just realised that even though $g \in H^{1/2}$, it does not imply that $|\nabla u|{H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)}$ is well-defined, but rather that $|\nabla u|{L^2(\partial\Omega)}$ is well-defined by the defintion.

But if $g\in H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$, then $\nabla g$ is only in $H^{-1/2}(\partial\Omega)$ and not necessarily in $L^2(\partial\Omega)$.

wait why? does this hold for any $s \in R$ ?
